# Problem with printing certain type of characters

Tags: c++

```
I have a function to print a binary tree:

  void printMe(const std::string& prefix, BinaryNode* node, bool isLeft)
    {
        if( node != nullptr )
        {
            std::cout << prefix;
            std::cout << (isLeft ? "├──────" : "└──────" );

//         print the value of the node
            std::cout << " (" <<nod->key<< ")" << " "<< std::endl;;

//         enter the next tree level - left and right branch
            printMe( prefix + (isLeft ? "│       " : "        "), node->right, true);
            printMe( prefix + (isLeft ? "│       " : "        "), node->left, false);
        }
    }

    void printMe()
    {
        printMe(" ",this->root, false);
    }
```

As you see, I'm trying to print special charactars `├──────`

When I try to compile, I get an error that the encoding methode have change since Im tring to use illegal characters. How can I print those characters anyway ?

Im using codeBlocks as my IDE, and the encoding is UTF-8.

When I try to print a tree this is an example to the output I get:

[image]

If anyone knows how to fix it, I'll be very greatful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The terminal is using a different character encoding than your C code. Always a danger when trying to do fancy text formatting

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ ASCII Art" or "C++ draw ASCII".